# How to fix vulnerabilities through yarn.lock file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, package.json

i m running the `yarn audit` in my react application and i get a report of around **150 warnings**.
I have to mention that i m using the `resolutions` into package.json, but the list is getting longer, so i thought to find efficient way.

I have added some, and i managed to **silent** the audit tool.

```
  "resolutions": {
    "jest-diff": "20.0.3",
    "nth-check": "^2.0.1",
    "loader-utils": "1.4.1",
    "glob-parent": "^5.1.2",
    "trim": "^0.0.3",
    "postcss":"7.0.36",
    "shell-quote": "1.7.3",
    "json5":"1.0.2",
    "trim-newlines":"3.0.1"
  },
```

I thought, instead of searching and digging on the internet for each error,
**maybe i can solve them in the `yarn.lock` itself.??**

I attach 2 of the errors and i analyse my thought process:

[![enter image description here][1]][1].

1. The first one is on the `loader-utils` package, which is dependency of `@storybook/addon-essentials`.

   **Thought process**:  check into the `yarn.lock` to find the place that `loader-utils` is used and change the version to the `patched` one like on the screenshot.

On the line that `@storybook/addon-assentials` is mentioned, it does not add the `loader-utils`. Shouldnt it have been mentioned here?
But `loader-utils` is used 41 times, as other dependencies...none for `@storybook/addon-assentials`...
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

**Extra question on the report:** The path that is mentioned on the reports, it does not exist into `node_modules` folder.
e.g.: `@storybook/addon-essentials > @storybook/core-common > babel-loader > loader-utils` (so, how can we use it for our advantage?).

PS: i know that audit tool is not the best tool and it reports false alarms as well.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9qRN.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xc9j7.png

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't edit the lock file, as that file is generated by the script. If you change it, the same error will pop up again after running the script again. Instead, fix the problem in your dependencies or your script. If you need to, you can remove the lock file and run your script again after fixing your issues.

Comment: hm. yes you are right we should not manually change it. But should i search one by one for 150 issues ? thats crazy :)